# AIX portmapper reported listening at port 32771. Why is it not the nlockmgr process?

Tags: security, aix, rpc

I am trying to calm my security group which believes *portmapper* is listening at port 32771.  My host is running AIX 7.1.  I do not have access to the GNU network utilities here.

rpcinfo(8), both remotely and locally, gives me output saying *nlockmgr* is listening at port 32771.  I'm including *mountd* and *status* for comparison.

```
$ rpcinfo -p
program vers proto   port  service
 100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
 100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
 100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
 100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
 100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
 100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
 [snip]
 100005    1   tcp  32770  mountd
 100005    2   tcp  32770  mountd
 100005    3   tcp  32770  mountd
 100021    1   tcp  32771  nlockmgr
 100021    2   tcp  32771  nlockmgr
 100021    3   tcp  32771  nlockmgr
 100021    4   tcp  32771  nlockmgr
 100024    1   tcp  32772  status
```

lsof(8) and ps(1) on the local host to point to *portmapper* itself.  (lsof finds no mention of 32771 in IPv4.)

```
$ sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6 | grep (portmap and 3277[012])
COMMAND     PID      USER FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
portmap     3735666  0     3u  IPv6 0xf10005000206c3b8      0t0  TCP *:111[portmapper] (LISTEN)
portmap     3735666  0     4u  IPv6 0xf100050000161200      0t0  UDP *:111[portmapper]
rpc.mount   4784282  0     3u  IPv6 0xf10005000017fbb8      0t0  TCP *:32770[mountd] (LISTEN)
portmap     3735666  0     5u  IPv6 0xf100050002116a00      0t0  UDP *:32771
rpc.statd   3801234  1     4u  IPv6 0xf10005000214ebb8      0t0  TCP *:32772[status] (LISTEN)

$ ps -ef | grep [3]735666
root  3735666  3080400   0   Dec 16      -  0:52 /usr/sbin/portmap

$ ps -ef | grep [4]784282
root  4784282  3080400   0   Dec 16      -  0:02 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd

$ ps -ef | grep [3]801234
daemon  3801234  3080400   0   Dec 16      -  0:00 /usr/sbin/rpc.statd -d 0 -t 50

$ netstat -Aan | grep (111 and 3277[012])
Active Internet connections (including servers)
PCB/ADDR         Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address      Foreign Address    (state)
f10005000206c3b8 tcp        0      0  *.111                 *.*                   LISTEN
f100050000161200 udp        0      0  *.111                 *.*
f10005000017fbb8 tcp        0      0  *.32770               *.*                   LISTEN
f10005000206cbb8 tcp        0      0  *.32771               *.*                   LISTEN
f100050002116a00 udp        0      0  *.32771               *.*
f10005000214ebb8 tcp        0      0  *.32772               *.*                   LISTEN
```

netcat(1), from a RHEL host, reports port 32771 is active.  Our security scanner specifically calls out *portmapper* associated with port 32771 and that's what the security group is focusing on.  The scanner doesn't care about the other high numbered ports associated with other normal RPC services, such as *mountd* and *status*.  IBM has no security advisories for *portmapper*.  I cannot configure *portmapper* to use a different port for the *nlockmgr* RPC service.

What gives with *portmapper*?  Shouldn't there be a *nlockmgr* process running?  How can I explain it to my security team?  Obviously my knowledge of portmapper is limited.

Answer (score 1):

The output of lsof shows you clearly which process is listening on the port 32771:

```
portmap     3735666  0     5u  IPv6 0xf100050002116a00      0t0  UDP *:32771
```

You can **IPv6** is jest tells you that v6 is supported as well. The output of  **rpcinfo** shows which services (not processes!) are registered. I read the both results together as:

> The **portmap** process have registered **nlockmgr** service, which
>   listen on UDP socket, port 32771.

The confising bit is that ouotput of rpcbind shows nlockmgr only on TCP, but this might be the result of truncated output.

Comment: Never any doubt a process was listening at 32771.  Why is the ps showing portmapper instead of nlockmgr, as it is with other rpc processes like mount and status?  

This is on AIX.  I do not have a similar situation on RHEL for comparison.